# Should i draw coregraphics ellipse or just use some images for my 2D Game Program

Tags: iphone, 2d, game-engine, ellipse

i m about to develop one iPhone Game in 2D graphics, i am not sure about the performance of application when drawing the images frequently for game play and using some images instead....
please suggest

Comment: For the sake of self-education you should try both. It's not like a month of work - only few hours ;)

Answer (score 0):

Neither should impact performance much.  If either gives you problems, you are probably doing it wrong.

That being said, coregraphics ellipse is probably going to be very ugly.  I'd suggest using images.